# ¿Como accedo a método de otra clase? (PHP POO MVC)

Tags: php, mvc, poo, clase, herencia

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.
Estoy aprendiendo POO desde hace poco y MVC y me complique un poco con este tema, al punto de empezar a meter cientos de métodos en una misma clase por no terminar de entender lo que planteo a continuación: Hay veces que necesitaría acceder a un método de una clase que no tengo heredada y no se como hacerlo, es decir: si tengo una clase adminControlador extends mainModel pero desde la clase adminControlador necesito un método que está en clienteControlador (por poner un ejemplo), entonces ¿como debería hacer?

Comment: Depende.. para que queres acceder a ese metodo? para obtener un valor? deberias volver a estudiar como es un modelo de orientado a objetos entonces, porque lo que estas preguntando es como crear un objeto y luego acceder a sus metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una instancia de ese objeto y mandar llamar su método

```
client = new AlgunaClase();
client->metodoPublico(); // Función sin argumento.
client->metodoPublicoConArgumento($variable); // Funcion con variable
```